# difference between OOP concepts and design patterns in java(which is more important)

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

i'm wondering if the design pattern and OOP concepts are the same. Someone just told me that they are the same. Can you give me guys the difference of the two? And which is a must learn first before I go to android developing?

Comment: These are two different things *by definition*

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is OOP and Design Patterns related?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478773/how-is-oop-and-design-patterns-related)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Design patterns and OOP are not the same.  A design pattern is a proven, battle-tested way of solving some problem.

**Edit**:  This questions sums it up: [How is OOP and Design Patterns related?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478773/how-is-oop-and-design-patterns-related)

Comment: Sorry i didn't notice that question. I type wrong keyword

Answer (score 2):

OOP is basic. Design Patterns (GoF23) are approaches to implement OOP concept. So you can learn OOP concepts first like "SOLID" principles, and then learn some easier patterns like "Factory Pattern", "Builder Pattern" to understand how those patterns reflected to OOP.

Comment: So the 4 basic principle is enough to understand the design pattern?

Comment: @user1708134 Of cause not. As you asked this question, I can assume there is a long way to go, and I just help you figure out where to start. ^-^